# open geotiff with gdal produces AttributeError: __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdal

I have a raster image and would like to open it with gdal to pull some information about the projection.

Opening with the following code works fine:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gtiff = gdal.Open(filename)
prj = gtiff.GetProjection()
# do some work
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
with gdal.Open(filename) as gtiff:
    prj = gtiff.GetProjection()
```

Instead an attribute error is displayed:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

I thought the latter is commonly accepted as better style. I'm using Python 3.4.5 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc. (anaconda).

Comment: It looks like whoever created that library didn't implement the context manager protocol on that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python relies on "magic methods" for many of its paradigms. The call to `len(x)`, for instance, calls `x.__len__()`. Equalities like `>` or `>=` also use magic methods that are double-underscored.

The `with X as x` paradigm of Python relies on two magic methods: `X.__enter__` and `X.__exit__`. The class returned by `gdal.Open` is a `gdal.Dataset`, which does not have these methods. It therefore throws an error when using a `with as` statement like you provided.

The proper way to open and close a `gdal.Dataset` is:

```
import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('filename.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
# do something
del ds
```

Deleting the `Dataset` will ensure that changes were written to the file. You can also write those changes by running `ds.FlushCache()`

[Doc about Python's `with as` statements](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

[Python's special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Comment: Just to make the answer complete: Is there a specific reason why these methods don't exist? Or is this sth that could be relatively easy added (I guess conserving backward compatinility wouldn't be a problem)?

Comment: [Del does not "delete" anything in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__). This method is really unreliable, although GDAL's Python bindings basically do not offer another choice.